# jqGrid - how to operate with lookup columns?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I have Orders table with StreetId column. I need to display and operate with that column on my UI in the jqGrid using inline-editor with autocompletion.

Questions:
1. How to store StreetId related to StreetName in the column? I cannot find any options in colModel to specify both values. Should i create extra hidden column for StreetId to get it posted back after editions? What is common way for that? I cannot find examples :(
2. Where can i find example for jqGrid lookup fields with jQuery autocompletion?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at the `afterInsertRow: function(id, currentData, jsondata)` event of jqgrid. You could do something like

```
afterInsertRow: function(id, currentData, jsondata) {
    $(this).setCell(id, "column_name", "<input type='hidden'>");
}
```